# How to view Microsoft Document Imaging (MDI) files on a Mac?

Tags: mac, software, ms-office

I've received a bunch of MDI files which I need to open on a Mac Snow Leopard. Any way around this e.g. free readers available?

Answer (score 1):

MDI files were a proprietary file format used by Microsoft Office 2003 and 2007 on Windows. Searching around online, some people have luck opening them with QuickTime (which is already on your Mac), or [GraphicConverter](http://www.lemkesoft.com/content/188/graphicconverter.html). Not having access to these files, nor a direct Mac equivalent, without more information we would be unsure if this would work or not. Office 2008 and 2011 on the Mac won't open them.

The best way to view these (and free too, really), would be to have a Windows using friend to open them in Windows and export as another file type.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a Windows system, Microsoft has a [MDI to TIFF](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30328) that you can use.  It's a command line tool that runs on XP, Vista, 7, 8 and 10.  You won't need to install Office 2003 or 2007.

There's an free online utility:  [Zamzar Free Online File Conversion](http://www.zamzar.com/convert/mdi-to-pdf/)  Disclaimer:  I am not a huge fan of sites like this, but I have used them in a pinch.  Be sure to read all the Ts & Cs before submitting your documents.

Personally, I would get ahold of a windows machine, even if it was a Virtual Machine (like Virtual Box) and just use the official Microsoft converter.  I am leery about software or services offered for free.